# Shopping Centers Database by Center Type

Tags: data, business-analyst

I am trying to find a free database which would have the shopping centers in US by center type (i.e. outlet, mall, strip). Could you please advice? I checked BA Desktop but our version does not have Center_Class_ID which would at least narrow it down to Power Center, Lifestyle, Super Regional.

Comment: The [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be a more suitable site to research/ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at the OpenStreetMap dataset.  It contains a fair amount of POI data, including some about stores and shopping malls.  However, I am not sure how in depth the data you need is and whether OSM might be too general or incomplete.  At first glance, the shop, amenity, and landuse tags might be of use to you.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:shop%3Dmall